# <Axis2> No extension base type element generated when using wsdl2java

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

I was trying to use the Axis2 wsdl2java command

```
wsdl2java -uri somefile.wsdl -o src -ss
```

to generate classes from wsdl/xsd files and running into this problem.

say, there's a complex type defined as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="ctype:IdentifierType">
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

where anyType is defined as

```
<xs:complexType name="IdentifierType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="scheme" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The generated Java class has a getter and setter for the named attribute "id" of MyType, successfully. But there was neither local field member nor getter and setter to handle the "scheme" of IdentifierType.

Is there anything I am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ADB binding does not support complex type, I've changed to xmlbeans, and it worked well, though the implemention are more trivial.